# Is there any hardware wallet available for Ethereum?

Tags: wallets, cold-storage, hardware-wallets

What are the various available hardware wallets for Ethereum?

Comment: Converted to wiki since it's a type of 'list of X' questions that contain enough value to avoid deletion.

Comment: The selected answer is no longer up to date, please see [this updated answer](https://ethereum.stackexchange.com/questions/1707/is-there-any-hardware-wallet-available-for-ethereum/10439#10439) for latest info.

Comment: See also https://ethereum.stackexchange.com/questions/1239/what-is-the-recommended-way-to-safely-store-ether

Answer (score 5, accepted):

There is no dedicated and fully supported hardware wallet for Ethereum.

There have been three announcements made so far:

- [Troth](https://medium.com/@Digix/offline-hardware-wallet-for-ethereum-troth-e1a75283f3bd#.wgefvzwyd) by Digix
- A hardware wallet by [Jaxx.io](http://jaxx.io) by end of 2016
- Ledger Blue to be shipped later the year ([an announcement about a demo Ethereum app BOLOS](https://www.reddit.com/r/ethereum/comments/49je5f/innovating_with_bolos_building_an_ethereum/) - the operating system it runs)

It isn't trivial, but not that complicated to include native support in Trezor compared to creating a wallet from scratch.

Meanwhile you can use a solution like [Quroum Wallet](http://quorumwallet.com/) together with Trezor. See the announcement on [Reddit](https://www.reddit.com/r/ethereum/comments/498ltg/quorum_using_bitcoin_hardware_wallets_to_secure/) and [this blog post explaining how it works](https://medium.com/@alexberegszaszi/quorum-using-bitcoin-keys-with-ethereum-ad44cf28fb20).

Comment: I think this answer is outdated now?

Comment: Yes, outdated, I have updated [this answer](https://ethereum.stackexchange.com/questions/1707/is-there-any-hardware-wallet-available-for-ethereum/10439#10439) with the latest info.

Answer (score 10):

Update: 2017-06-11

Available hardware wallets for Ethereum (in alphabetical order):

- [Digital Bitbox](https://www.hardware-wallets.de/out/digital-bitbox-ethereum)
- [KeepKey](https://www.keepkey.com/) (now [out of beta](https://www.keepkey.com/2017/01/31/ethereum-keepkey-goes-production/))
- [Ledger Blue](https://www.ledgerwallet.com/products/9-ledger-blue)
- [Ledger Nano S](https://www.ledgerwallet.com/products/12-ledger-nano-s)
- [Trezor](https://trezor.io/) (in beta, see [this answer](https://ethereum.stackexchange.com/questions/1758/is-trezor-compatible-with-ethereum/17248#17248) for details)

Answer (score 7):

Ledger started shipping the Nano S [Ether hardware wallet](https://bitcoinnewsmagazine.com/ether-hardware-wallet-ledger-nano-s-review/) the last week of July 2016. Works for ETH, ETC and bitcoin at a cost of $65.

Comment: Downvoted. This only lists 1 of 4 available wallets and the pricing info is no longer accurate.

Comment: I have updated [this answer](https://ethereum.stackexchange.com/questions/1707/is-there-any-hardware-wallet-available-for-ethereum/10439#10439) with the latest info.

Answer (score 5):

[Trezor](https://www.bitcointrezor.com) is a popular hardware wallet that supports Bitcoin and other alt coins

[Troth](https://medium.com/@Digix/offline-hardware-wallet-for-ethereum-troth-e1a75283f3bd#.wgefvzwyd) is on the way

> Troth is an Ethereum hardware vault for safely storing your Ether and
>   Ethereum based tokens. We are looking at the end of March / Early
>   April for the first working prototype. Troth is a Raspberry PI within,
>   complete with a Touchscreen and 5mb camera in a custom encasement,
>   prop firmware (that will be security audited), zero internet
>   connectivity providing a true offline wallet storage solution.

Comment: I don't believe Trezor supports Ethereum yet. They added "firmware update that brings in Ethereum support once specific wallets implement the necessary components to further their compatibility" per [https://www.ethnews.com/trezor-adds-ethereum-support](this article). Coming soon with no apparent ETA for their own web wallet to support it. What other altcoins does trezor support? I'm only aware of bitcoin.

Comment: Downvoted.  This answer is way out of date and links to a broken medium article.  There are good hardware options now, please see [my answer](https://ethereum.stackexchange.com/a/17710/9715) below.

Comment: @JonathanCross too silly that you down voted and posted link to your answer. `community wiki` is something you can edit and add your point. Spend some here and see how this website works. Good luck pal.

Comment: @niksmac Thanks for the feedback.  When editing an answer, the criteria indicates that this is only for minor corrections and should not change the meaning.  Since your answer is mostly about Troth, an "edit" did not seem appropriate.  I went ahead and updated [this answer](https://ethereum.stackexchange.com/questions/1707/is-there-any-hardware-wallet-available-for-ethereum/10439#10439) as it was substantially similar to mine.

Answer (score 2):

At the moment available ETH hardware wallets are

- Trezor
- KeepKey
- Ledger Blue & Nano S

Find more details [here](https://plusethereum.net/ethereum-hardware-wallet/).

Comment: The linked website is full of referral links.  Not cool.

Comment: Jonathan Cross, you are right, but the article is still valuable.

Answer (score 0):

There are a many hardware wallets available for Ethereum as shown here at the [Hardware Wallet comparison](https://www.hardware-wallets.de) with the little icons. For example the ledger nano s.