# Is Trezor compatible with Ethereum

Tags: ether, cold-storage, trezor

Can I use the Trezor hardware wallet for cold storage of ETH?

Comment: Yes, please see my answer below.

Comment: As this is a popular question you may want to accept the newer answer (people appear to be downvoting the current accepted answer only because it is out of date).

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Update 2017-06-05

**YES** -- Trezor is now compatible with Ethereum (ETH), Classic (ETC) and ERC-20 tokens [via firmware 1.5.0](https://blog.trezor.io/trezor-firmware-updated-to-1-5-0-7a402d3e9f89).  Can use the [Trezor (Beta) Web Wallet](https://beta-wallet.trezor.io/) or [MyEtherWallet.com](https://myetherwallet.com/).

Answer (score 1):

Update 2017: it is now. Ignore the below.

**Update 11/23/16**

> Firmware Update (1.4.0) for Ethereum Developers
>
> This firmware update also brings Ethereum support to TREZOR. However, this is only the first piece of the puzzle. In order for the users to use TREZOR as a secure storage for their Ether, ethereum wallets have to first implement the necessary components. We are working with Mist on the next step of the process, to bring a practical use of this update to our users.

https://blog.trezor.io/secure-two-factor-authentication-with-trezor-u2f-e940fd5a60af#.z65p8mya5

So...not yet still.

Answer (score -2):

EDIT: At the time of posting this in early 2016 the answer was valid. Since it has been added to the Trezor firmware.

Trezor is not directly compatible yet, but it can be used with a solution like what [Quorum Wallet](http://quorumwallet.com/) does.

See the announcement on [Reddit](https://www.reddit.com/r/ethereum/comments/498ltg/quorum_using_bitcoin_hardware_wallets_to_secure/) and [this blog post explaining how it works](https://medium.com/@alexberegszaszi/quorum-using-bitcoin-keys-with-ethereum-ad44cf28fb20).

EDIT: See this other topic for alternative hardware wallets: [Is there any hardware wallet available for Ethereum?](https://ethereum.stackexchange.com/questions/1707/is-there-any-hardware-wallet-available-for-ethereum/1947#1947)