# How do I transfer balance to another address? w/o syncing with network

Tags: transactions, accounts, wallet-transfer

I have a single ethereum address that has ether in it from 2015 when I was playing around with Geth and the CLI. I have removed the blockchain and associated homebrew files from my computer. How can I transfer that balance from that ether account into something else? Is there a way to do it without syncing with the network? Could I just somehow import the address into a wallet like Jaxx? Thanks for the help.

Answer (score 9):

If you want to send a transaction using a full node (you mentioned Geth and the CLI), the full node must be in sync

You are correct that your alternative is to use a light wallet such as Jaxx

Answer (score 7):

In the end, you simply need to sign a transaction using the private key to that account and broadcast it to the network. There are a variety of ways to do so, depending on your skill level.

1. GUI Wallets like Jaxx, MyEtherWallet, Exodus, Mist.
2. Use a library like **[ethereumjs-wallet](https://github.com/ethereumjs/ethereumjs-wallet)** or [ethers.js](https://github.com/ethers-io/ethers.js).
3. You can broadcast any signed raw transaction via https://etherscan.io/pushTx

Answer (score 4):

Use https://www.myetherwallet.com . You don't need to download the blockchain for this to work. It's meant to use client-side JavaScript.

See [What is the recommended way to safely store Ether?](https://ethereum.stackexchange.com/questions/1239/what-is-the-recommended-way-to-safely-store-ether) for more details. Also search this site for "MyEtherWallet".

Answer (score 2):

You could use https://www.myetherwallet.com/#send-transaction to send your funds to poloniex

Follow these instructions:

1-Find your keystore file. (%appdata%/Ethereuem/keystore in windows).

2-Open MyEtherWallet and go to the “Send Ether” tab.

3-Select your keystore file or enter your private key.

4-If a password appears, enter your password and then hit “unlock wallet”.

[image]

5-then go to Go to Poloniex and get a deposit address.

[image]
[image]
6-Go back to MyEtherWallet and paste that deposit address into the “To Address:” field.

7-Enter the amount to send. It is recommended to test with a small amount first.
[image]

Comment: This has been flagged as a duplicate answer.

Comment: Yeah, i wanted just to give the same answer to two similar questions. So how to deal with that ?

Comment: If the question is a duplicate, choose Close and the duplicate option.  If it's not a duplicate, the answer should usually not be the same. This answer has extra details that aren't asked in the question.

Comment: If you have an identical twin, each of you should be able to answer one of them.