# mist.exe , Ethereum-Wallet.exe not a Win32 valid application

Tags: mist, wallets, windows

I can't install any kind of official wallet on my computer.
When i try to run the exe from the downloaded content all i get is this error **not a valid Win32 application.**
I can not run on my Windows XP SP 3 32-bit computer.
I have chose to download the proper version for my computer :
Mist-win32-0-8-0.zip
or 
Ethereum-Wallet-win32-0-8-0.zip
but nothing works.
Also if i try to run geth.exe i get an error about a msvcrt.dll :

"**The procedure entry point fopen_s could not be located in the dynamic link library msvcrt.dll**"

How long should i wait until a proper 32bit version will be released ?

All i want is a secure official wallet for ETH to make transactions specially to receive ETH from faucets or mining on a cloud mining and to sell it on a an exchange later.
Thanks.

Answer (score 2):

Official support for Windows XP [ended](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/help/14223/windows-xp-end-of-support) 2 years ago (April 2014).

When you're dealing with currency of any type, you want your machine to be as secure as possible. Who knows what vulnerabilities have been found in XP in last 2 years...

> All i want is a secure official wallet for ETH to make transactions
>   specially to receive ETH from faucets or mining on a cloud mining and
>   to sell it on a an exchange later.

A *secure* official wallet relies on your system being inherently secure.

Consider using a remote online service, such as [My Ether Wallet](https://www.myetherwallet.com/). You're moving your trust from the security of your OS to the security of your browser. Running an up-to-date browser on an out-of-date OS is still not ideal, but perhaps the safer of the two options.

Associated previous thread: [What is the recommended way to safely store Ether?](https://ethereum.stackexchange.com/questions/1239/what-is-the-recommended-way-to-safely-store-ether)

Comment: Thank you for the answer. Yes i know the XP support ended long time ago but i really don't care even if i get a powerful virus because i can reinstall windows over and over :) However you are right ,we are talking about real money here and my work , so creating a wallet on a XP computer is not a good idea despite to my antivirus and firewall guardians .Can't access  myetherwallet website from Chrome **(www.myetherwallet.com uses an unsupported protocol.)**, the browser doesn't let me , says is unsecure SSL or something, but i will use Firefox

Comment: It's not the point that you can reinstall Windows, but rather that if someone is able to compromise your machine then they can probably compromise a wallet local to that machine as well. Antivirus and firewalls are only as secure as the underlying OS allows them to be, and it's not their job to protect against vulnerabilities that the OS vendors are no longer willing to fix. I'd seriously consider upgrading, even if it's only to Windows 7. My suggestion of using an online service is really only marginally better... (In light of keyloggers, etc.)

Comment: The error you're seeing with Chrome will be "ERR_SSL_VERSION_OR_CIPHER_MISMATCH". It's because Windows XP is so old that it doesn't support the correct cipher suites... :(

Comment: can't upgrade to windows 7 because i guess my old machine 2 gb RAM on core 2 duo can't handle it so until i save the money for a new computer the only way is to use (create) myetherwallet wiith firefox ? . Its no rush for me to make a wallet and getting started with ETH too like i do with bitcoin from various faucets,etc,  but i wanna save/work for my ETHs because i have a felling that this crypto will skyrocket price over time to become more valuable than BTC :)

Answer (score 0):

I remember reading that most if not all Ethereum apps are targeted for x64 architectures. This is motivated by the the proof of work function's [design](https://github.com/ethereum/wiki/wiki/Ethash-Design-Rationale); in short many IO operations instead of computational steps in order to make it difficult to implement the PoW in hardware (i.e. ASICs).

This, in turn, implies moving around a number of GBs of data in RAM which may become a bottleneck for 32-bit systems as they can manage at most 4 GB (2^32) of address space).

Comment: my system has 2 gb of ram :) with a core 2 duo . Saving money to buy a new computer , long way to go, anyway ,my friend from a forum said he has a 64-bit computer and he tried to run Mist but it isn't working for him either. I guess we in estearn europe have some weird computer configuration/arhitecture or something. Anyways we will try an online version for wallet.