# Are there Ethereum Wallets (other that Mist) that provide support for test-network

Tags: wallets, testnets, parity, myetherwallet, jaxx

I was going through a list of Ethereum wallets from [here](https://www.weusecoins.com/ethereum-wallets/) and [here](https://ethereum.stackexchange.com/questions/1239/what-is-the-recommended-way-to-safely-store-ether). Some good or I should say popular ones other than Mist were Jaxx and MyEtherWallet.
But I was concerned if any Ethereum wallet provides functionality of connection to test-network. Like In Mist I can connect to a test network and play around with ethers and also can test my contracts over private network before deploying it on public blockchain.
Are there any Ethereum wallets available which fullfill following criteria:

1. Is a Light-wallet
2. Provides support of custom Tokens
3. Provides support for test network.

Is there any chance of Mist releasing a light-wallet?

Answer (score 8):

The word light-wallet or light-client can mean a number of things. There is the fast-sync'd versions of geth and parity which reduce the amount of data necessary on your hard drive.

There are also wallets available that have their own node infrastructure that you can use without syncing the chain:

- [Metamask](https://metamask.io/)
- [MyEtherWallet](https://www.myetherwallet.com)

You can change the node MEW connects to in the top-right corner to access (at the time of this edit)

- Ethereum
- Ethereum Classic
- Testnet: Ropsten, Kovan, Rinkeby
- Expanse
- Ubiq
- RSK
- Your own custom node / chain

Comment: is there a 2022 update to this question?

Answer (score 6):

MyEtherWallet has testnets: Ropsten
[image]

Answer (score 2):

> 1. Is a Light-wallet

If you are nosy, you can try out the latest [nightly](https://github.com/paritytech/parity/releases/tag/nightly) build of Parity and run:

```
parity --light
```

To play around with the experimental light client. If you just want to use your parity wallet from a remote device, you can run a server or workstation with:

```
parity --public-node --ui-interface <public ip>
```

Where public IP is either your public or your local area network IP.

> 2. Provides support of custom Tokens

Parity supports a decentralized token registry, everyone can register a custom ERC20 token. All registered tokens will be displayed in your Accounts balances:

[image: Screenshot]

> 3. Provides support for test network.

And last but not least, Parity supports [several test networks](https://github.com/paritytech/parity/wiki/Chain-specification#chain-presets-available):

```
parity --chain kovan
parity --chain ropsten
parity --chain morden
```

*Disclosure: I work for Parity.*