# Buying ERC20 tokens on Development stage

Tags: erc-20, ropsten

How can we simulate buying ERC20 tokens from a contract deployed on Ropsten for Development and Testing purposes without involving real Ethers?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

in a nutshell :

1. you deploy your ERC20 or use an already deployed one
2. connect your wallet to ropsten exp metamask
3. get some free ethers from a faucet
4. buy your token using your faucet ethers.

Comment: Can we do this through myetherwallet.com or which wallet will be best for this case?

Comment: yes you can https://ethereum.stackexchange.com/questions/9054/are-there-ethereum-wallets-other-that-mist-that-provide-support-for-test-netwo