# install ethereum wallet on local computer

Tags: ether, wallets

I want to be able to transfer ether from an online exchange to a private wallet on my local computer. How can I install a safe standard wallet? Do I need to install ethereum blockchain first? If so, no problem, but where and how? What is Mist?

Answer (score 0):

> What is Mist?

### [Please read first](https://github.com/ethereum/mist/wiki#please-read-first)

In the GitHub wiki I've linked above you can read about the Mist and the difference between Mist and Ethereum wallet.

---

> Do I need to install ethereum blockchain first?

Kind of. You will have to syncronise with the blockchain.

---

> How can I install a safe standard wallet?

There is a [**great post about it**](https://ethereum.stackexchange.com/a/1245/9938), please have a look.