# Which wallet should I use for Ethereum?

Tags: wallets, ledger-nano-s

Could someone please suggest a safe wallet to use for Ethereum please?

I would ideally want to use a desktop wallet- I saw Exodus but I have heard it has high fee costs. I will be buying a ledger nano S once they are shipping again but in the meantime I want a safe desktop wallet for Ethereum.

Comment: See also https://ethereum.stackexchange.com/questions/1239/what-is-the-recommended-way-to-safely-store-ether

Comment: Related: [Ethereum desktop wallet which works](https://softwarerecs.stackexchange.com/q/50163/3474).

Answer (score 1):

MetaMask is very safe but it is Chrome based.  You control your private key which lives only on your desktop.  I also use Coinomi on my Android phone.  I have heard good things about Exodus if you're looking for a true desktop wallet but I haven't tried it myself.  For me, MetaMask is just as good as a desktop wallet and has the added benefit of being able to automatically interact with decentralized exchanges such as EtherDelta.  Good luck!