# How to unlock accounts programmatically after the node has started?

Tags: go-ethereum, accounts, security, testing

Is there any way of just unlocking accounts without opening the console with `geth`?

I'm writing some scripts to automate cluster generation and I wish I could just call `geth` to unlocking some accounts without starting another instance or attaching to an existing one.

---

### Edit

If I run something like:

```
geth --genesis "$GENESIS_FILE" --datadir "$DATA_DIR" --networkid "$NETWORK_ID" \
     --password <(echo -n $ACCOUNT_PASSWD) --unlock "$UNLOCK_INDEXES" \
     --exec '""' attach > /dev/null
```

after the node startup, the **accounts are not unlocked**.

The only way I've managed to get accounts unlocked was to unlock them when running `geth` in order to start the node.

Answer (score 18, accepted):

Just to clarify:

- You would like to run a geth node starting up with the accounts all locked as per the default
- You later want to run a 'geth attach' command to unlock one or more accounts for a period of time

You can use use the following command to attach to your geth node to unlock an account using the personal.unlockAccount(...) JavaScript API (https://github.com/ethereum/go-ethereum/wiki/JavaScript-Console#personalunlockaccount), where the third parameter is the duration in seconds:

```
> geth --exec "personal.unlockAccount(eth.accounts[0], 'password', 1000)" attach
true
```

Or you can create a file, e.g. unlock.js with the following content:

```
personal.unlockAccount(eth.accounts[0], 'password', 1000);
```

And then use the following command to unlock the account:

```
> geth --exec "loadScript('unlock.js')" attach
true
```

Responding to the question below regarding the default duration, if no duration is specified then a duration of 0 is implied. And a duration of 0 will unlock the account until the program exits, e.g. there is no expiry.

From https://github.com/ethereum/go-ethereum/blob/master/internal/ethapi/api.go#L239-L254 :

```
// UnlockAccount will unlock the account associated with the given address with
// the given password for duration seconds. If duration is nil it will use a
// default of 300 seconds. It returns an indication if the account was unlocked.
func (s *PrivateAccountAPI) UnlockAccount(addr common.Address, password string, duration *uint64) (bool, error) {
    const max = uint64(time.Duration(math.MaxInt64) / time.Second)
    var d time.Duration
    if duration == nil {
        d = 300 * time.Second
    } else if *duration > max {
        return false, errors.New("unlock duration too large")
    } else {
        d = time.Duration(*duration) * time.Second
    }
    err := s.am.TimedUnlock(accounts.Account{Address: addr}, password, d)
    return err == nil, err
}
```

And from https://github.com/ethereum/go-ethereum/blob/master/accounts/account_manager.go#L181-L216 where you can see the comment `A timeout of 0 unlocks the account until the program exits`:

```
// TimedUnlock unlocks the given account with the passphrase. The account
// stays unlocked for the duration of timeout. A timeout of 0 unlocks the account
// until the program exits. The account must match a unique key file.
//
// If the account address is already unlocked for a duration, TimedUnlock extends or
// shortens the active unlock timeout. If the address was previously unlocked
// indefinitely the timeout is not altered.
func (am *Manager) TimedUnlock(a Account, passphrase string, timeout time.Duration) error {
    a, key, err := am.getDecryptedKey(a, passphrase)
    if err != nil {
        return err
    }

    am.mu.Lock()
    defer am.mu.Unlock()
    u, found := am.unlocked[a.Address]
    if found {
        if u.abort == nil {
            // The address was unlocked indefinitely, so unlocking
            // it with a timeout would be confusing.
            zeroKey(key.PrivateKey)
            return nil
        } else {
            // Terminate the expire goroutine and replace it below.
            close(u.abort)
        }
    }
    if timeout > 0 {
        u = &unlocked{Key: key, abort: make(chan struct{})}
        go am.expire(a.Address, u, timeout)
    } else {
        u = &unlocked{Key: key}
    }
    am.unlocked[a.Address] = u
    return nil
}
```

Comment: TY. One further question: the docs aren't clear in this point: if I supress the third argument `duration`, for how long the account will remain unlocked?

Comment: From the source code (see above), excluding the third duration argument would unlock the account until the program exits.

Comment: Github link not working .