# Unlocking accounts and making transactions in web3.js

Tags: transactions, web3js, accounts

This question is related to [this](https://ethereum.stackexchange.com/questions/1216/unlocking-accounts-for-a-back-office-app) one and [this](https://ethereum.stackexchange.com/questions/780/does-web3-js-have-the-functionality-to-create-new-accounts-and-unlock-an-account) one. It also has a partial answer [here](https://ethereum.stackexchange.com/questions/5844/do-i-have-to-unlock-my-account-in-geth-to-call-a-web3-eth-sign-in-javascript) and [here](https://ethereum.stackexchange.com/questions/3780/how-can-i-create-a-listener-for-new-transaction-with-ethereum-rpc-calls).

In the third link the account is being unlocked for a period of time using **web3.js**:

```
web3.personal.unlockAccount("0x..", "<passs>", 1000);
```

The unlock period parameter is optional.

How is it possible to check if [accounts](https://github.com/ethereum/wiki/wiki/JavaScript-API#web3ethaccounts) are locked (prior to making transactions)?

Are there any functionality consequences of unlocking an already unlocked account?

Comment: Is <pass> the private key? E.g. `let account = self.web3.eth.accounts.privateKeyToAccount(self.config.walletPrivateKey);` & `self.web3.eth.personal.unlockAccount(account.address, account.privateKey, 200)`

Comment: No, just a password used to encrypt the private key (that is later used in transactions).

Comment: Note that the personal API is legacy and no wallet in practice use this. Different wallets provide different providers to sign transactions. More information here: https://ethereum.stackexchange.com/questions/82531/connecting-the-wallet-of-a-user-to-your-dapp-web3-js-project/82532#82532

Answer (score 10, accepted):

There [currently isn't a method](https://github.com/ethereum/web3.js/blob/master/lib/web3/methods/personal.js) for checking whether an account is locked or not in the web3 JS API.

However, from [the code](https://github.com/ethereum/go-ethereum/blob/master/accounts/keystore/keystore.go#L332), if an account is already unlocked, then there's no problem calling unlock again.

```
// If the account address is already unlocked for a duration, TimedUnlock extends or
// shortens the active unlock timeout. If the address was previously unlocked
// indefinitely the timeout is not altered.
func (am *Manager) TimedUnlock(a Account, passphrase string, timeout time.Duration) error {
```

---

Why are we only looking at `TimedUnlock()`, which presumably only gets invoked if we pass the third parameter?

As you noted, the unlock period parameter is optional. If it isn't provided, then we call `Unlock()`, which is a wrapper around `TimedUnlock()`, but which passes `0` as the time period. Hence we only need consider the `TimedUnlock()` function in the explanation.

Comment: I have a design that may change and do not know yet which choice is best. I'll go with no time unlock for now (this would normally keep the account unlocked indefinitely).

Comment: I'd argue that there is a problem in unlocking an account over and over again and that is that the unlocking takes quite some time (~3s for me using latest geth).

Answer (score 8):

Here is a workaround to check if account is unlocked. It is not very beautiful but in most cases it works. **Use it only for development purposes on testnet or private net!!! Because "this sends out an actual transaction for which you have to pay gas" [Unlocking accounts and making transactions in web3.js](https://ethereum.stackexchange.com/questions/6903/unlocking-accounts-and-making-transactions-in-web3-js/12188?noredirect=1#comment13537_12188)**

```
function isAccountLocked(account) {
    try {
        web3.eth.sendTransaction({
            from: account,
            to: account,
            value: 0
        });
        return false;
    } catch (err) {
        return (err.message == "authentication needed: password or unlock");
    }
}

function unlockAccountsIfNeeded(accounts, passwords, unlock_duration_sec) {
    if (typeof(unlock_duration_sec)==='undefined') unlock_duration_sec = 300;

    for (let i = 0; i < accounts.length; i++) {
        if (isAccountLocked(accounts[i])) {
            console.log("Account " + accounts[i] + " is locked. Unlocking")
            web3.personal.unlockAccount(accounts[i], passwords[i], unlock_duration_sec);
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: This is indeed not very beautiful because this sends out an actual transaction for which you have to pay gas.

Comment: @AlexeyBarsuk nice script, i suggest to add unlock duration (0 unlocked as geth is running) web3.personal.unlockAccount(accounts[i], passwords[i], Duration);

Answer (score 7):

You can use [web3.eth.sign](http://web3js.readthedocs.io/en/1.0/web3-eth.html#sign) and check if it fails.

```
async function isUnlocked (web3, address) {
    try {
        await web3.eth.sign("", address);
    } catch (e) {
        return false;
    }
    return true;
}
```

Comment: Please give a little more detail in your answer. Providing a link without much context may not help the OP.

Comment: @Malone web3.eth.sign will throw "authentication needed: password or unlock" in case you are not unlocked

Answer (score 0):

This is a possible method, directly calling the JSON RPC method `personal_listWallets`:

```js
async function listWallets() {
    try {
        const result = await sendRPC_personal_listWallets();
        console.log(typeof result);
        return result;
    } catch (e) {
        return e;
    }
}

function sendRPC_personal_listWallets() {

    return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {

        web3.currentProvider.send({ method: "personal_listWallets", params: [], jsonrpc: "2.0", id: new Date().getTime() },
            function (error, result) { if (error) { reject(error); } else { resolve(result); } });
    }
    );
}
let wallets;
listWallets().then((r) => { console.log("ID:", r.id); wallets = r.result; console.log("Accounts:", wallets); });
```

Comment: Note that `personal` API is being deprecated and in practice no user wallet implements this. https://ethereum.stackexchange.com/questions/82531/connecting-the-wallet-of-a-user-to-your-dapp-web3-js-project/82532#82532

Comment: @MikkoOhtamaa can you provide any link to a notice of this - `personal` API being deprecated? I checked, all I could find is that of it's HTTP provider being deprecated here - https://web3js.readthedocs.io/en/v1.2.11/web3-eth-personal.html#providers

Comment: Unfortunately I cannot go to find sources for you after two years. However you can take my word on it: don't try to use it, it was bad idea in 2015 and it is still a bad idea.