# Custom Parity signer – programmatically unlock accounts for a certain time

Tags: parity, parity-signer

[image: Default Parity Signer]

How can I implement a custom transaction signer (which will unlock accounts on the fly) and tell parity client to use it?

I **don't want** to unlock all accounts at startup (and always keep them unlocked. Instead, I want to set some logic for account unlocking on each transaction, say:

```
if (isDay && accountAddress in [addr1, addr2, addr3])
    unlockAccount and signTransaction
else
    rejectTransaction
```

I'm looking into [JSONRPC signer module](https://github.com/paritytech/parity/wiki/JSONRPC-signer-module) as a possible option, but not able to connect to the Parity Signer UI using websockets

```
Connect Error: Error: Server responded with a non-101 status: 403
Response Headers Follow:
x-frame-options: SAMEORIGIN
x-xss-protection: 1; mode=block
x-content-type-options: nosniff
server: Parity/SignerUI
content-length: 524
content-type: text/html
connection: close
```

Answer (score 2):

Parity takes a command line option to keep certain accounts unlocked:

Example:

```
   --unlock 0x001fc7d7e506866aeab82c11da515e9dd6d32c25 --password password.txt
```

Comment: I don't want to unlock all accounts at startup.

Comment: @EdwardRuchevits then please clarify what you are looking for.

Comment: `--unlock` unlocks only listed accounts

Comment: @5chdn updated my question.

Comment: @MikkoOhtamaa And keeps them unlocked all the time. I don't want it. Please see my updated question.

Comment: @5chdn -> Use `web3.personal.unlockAccount()` with a timeout. See https://ethereum.stackexchange.com/a/12188/620 but @5chdn needs to clarify if Parity can unlock the account without the web ui. Geth does, but I am unsure about Parity.

Comment: Parity can do that, [yes](https://github.com/paritytech/parity/wiki/JSONRPC-personal-module#personal_unlockaccount).

Comment: Looks like I need to use https://github.com/paritytech/parity/wiki/JSONRPC-signer-module for this. The expected flow is: tx is sent and pending confirmation (could be obtained using `signer_requestsToConfirm`?), `signer_confirmRequest` or `signer_rejectRequest` executed automatically. Not sure how to use it tho (updated my answer again).

Answer (score 1):

You can unlock an account via RPC.

```
curl --data '{"method":"personal_unlockAccount","params":["0x8f0227d45853a50eefd48dd4fec25d5b3fd2295e","hunter2",null],"id":1,"jsonrpc":"2.0"}' -H "Content-Type: application/json" -X POST localhost:8545
```

For details, see https://wiki.parity.io/JSONRPC-personal-module#personal_unlockaccount