# Unlock remote account

Tags: solidity, contract-development, web3js, nodes, nodejs

I have smart contract deployed that accepts funds (via fallback function `function() payable { ... }`). Also I have frontend using web3 to send funds.

When I tested it with local node (and JSON wallets presented locally) evrything works fine - `web3.personal.unlockAccount(account, password)` unlocked account with data provided by user then funds sent to contract.

Now I deployed `geth` node on standalone VPS and connecting to it using code:

```
var Web3 = require('web3');
this.web3 = new Web3();
this.web3.setProvider(new Web3.providers.HttpProvider('http://my-node-addr.net:18545/'));

if(this.web3.isConnected()) {
  console.log('web3 connected');
} else {
  console.log('web3 NOT connected');
}
```

It shows that client connected successfully. But when I am trying to send funds code failed on line

```
web3.personal.unlockAccount(account, password);
```

with error `Error: no key for given address or file`. Of course, my node cannot contain all client's wallet file (nobody want to upload it).

Here is how I am sending transaction:

```
this.contract.sendTransaction({ from: account, value: amount, gas: 400000 })
.then(() => {
    // OK, everything fine!
})
.catch(error => {
    // I am here
    console.log('Oops...', 'Error happened during your payment: ' + error, 'error');
});
```

UPD: What I want: provide html page with fields "account", "password" and "amount" that allows users to send ethers to predefined address. Of course my node will not have `UTC-.....` files (wallets).

Comment: Have you considered to use MetaMask browser plugin to store client's wallets and send transactions from client side? You don't need to unlock any account in this case. Maybe, it helps to you.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Unlocking accounts and making transactions in web3.js](https://ethereum.stackexchange.com/questions/6903/unlocking-accounts-and-making-transactions-in-web3-js)

Comment: @ViktorBaranov I do not want to force clients to install pugins, chrome browser or anything else. All I want is to provide html page with "account" and "password" fields that allows users to sends etheres to predefined account.

Comment: @niksmac that question is totally unrelated because that OP hasn't any problems with unlocking accounts and as I see he means accounts whose wallets presented on target node. My question is about unlocking accounts whose wallets not presented on node.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The method `sendTransaction` works because geth has access to the private key. In your scenario since the private key is in the client geth has no access to it and will not be able to sign the transaction.

You need to sign the transaction in the client side and use `sendRawTransaction` to broadcast your signed transaction. You can use [eth-lightwallet](https://github.com/ConsenSys/eth-lightwallet/) to manage keys client side, if you want something more low level you can use [ethereumjs-tx](https://github.com/ethereumjs/ethereumjs-tx) to create and sign your own transactions.

Comment: To sign raw trasaction I need private key from user, right?

Comment: Yes, you need the user private key.