# Managing keys/accounts external to Geth?

Tags: go-ethereum, accounts, keymanagement

I know that Geth requires that you have your wallet files located in the ./keystore directory and that you are required to unlock an account before using it. However, one of our potential use cases is having a web application that allows users to log in and use their wallet with us managing/retrieving credentials with our data model. With Geth's current requirement, we would have to have upwards of thousands of wallet files sitting in the keystore. Is there a way to create and use an account without having this file in the keystore?

I'm afraid the answer is no, but wanted to make sure I haven't missed anything.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I believe I found the proper way to do this, per [this question](https://ethereum.stackexchange.com/questions/22993/unlock-remote-account). Using a RawTransaction and signing it yourself means that keys can be managed by the client and Geth will allow transactions to occur for that wallet/account without unlocking it.