# How to authenticate user using passphrase?

Tags: go-ethereum, metamask, authentication

While creating ethereum account(geth) account we need to enter the passphrase for respective account. Is there any way to authenticate the user using that passphrase from a front end?

Comment: The question title does not match the question, so it is confusing to understand what you try to ask

Comment: @MikkoOhtamaa modified title of question

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Simply use

```
web3.personal.unlockAccount("0x..", "<passs>", 1000);
```

You can find useful information in this [here](https://ethereum.stackexchange.com/questions/6903/unlocking-accounts-and-making-transactions-in-web3-js).